# How can I prove this property of binomial coefficients?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I was playing around with binomial coefficients and binomial expansions and I came across an interesting identity:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}{n \choose k}x^k=\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)x}$$

I have verified this for a few different values of n and wolfram alpha seems to agree (see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%5B%28n%20choose%20r%29*%281%2F%28r%2B1%29%29x%5Er%2C%7Br%2C0%2Cn%7D%5D)) but I'm not quite sure how to go about proving it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've tried writing the binomial coefficient out in its factorial definition and manipulating the factorials from there but it never ended up getting me anywhere

Comment: Probably by playing around with derivatives you can make that form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
(x+1)^{n+1}-1
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}{n+1\choose k}x^k-1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}{n+1\choose k}x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n+1\choose k+1}x^{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n+1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^{k+1}\\
&=(n+1)x\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac 1{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac 1{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k
&=\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)x}\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Comment: Wow. Vastly simple. Thanks!

Comment: Just one slight thing, shouldn't the upper limit of the summation change to $n$ on the third line?

Comment: @ASKASK Thank you! Yes, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Define $$f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}{n \choose k}x^k$$

$$g(x) = xf(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}{n \choose k}x^{k+1}$$

Then we have $g'(x) =\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}x^{k} = (1+x)^n$.

Since $g(0) = 0$, we get $g(x) = \frac{(1+x)^{n+1} -1}{n+1}$, then the expression of $f(x)$ accordingly.