# Expression Similar to Binomial Theorem Sum

Tags: summation, closed-form, binomial-theorem

I have the following expression,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n+1-k}x^ky^{n-k}$$

This seems awfully close to the output of the binomial theorem (for $(x+y)^{n}$). Thus my question is, is the above a known identity/expression? I'd like to get it in a nicer form if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the variable of summation to $j:=n-k$ and the sum can be written
$$
x^n\sum_{j=0}^n{n\choose j}\frac1{j+1}\left(\frac yx\right)^j.\tag1
$$
You can now evaluate the sum in (1) using [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1225583/215011)
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k+1}{n \choose k}x^k=\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}-1}{(n+1)x}
$$
to obtain
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n+1-k}x^ky^{n-k}=\frac{(x+y)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}{(n+1)y}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Take your basic binomial theorem
$$(x+t)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^kt^{n-k}\ .$$
Integrate for $t$ from 0 to $y$:
$$\frac1{n+1}\bigl((x+y)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}\bigr)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk x^k\frac{y^{n+1-k}}{n+1-k}\ .$$
Divide by $y$:
$$\frac1{n+1}\frac{(x+y)^{n+1}-x^{n+1}}y=\langle\hbox{your sum}\rangle\ .$$